# Getting password from mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a login method and I need to get a password from the corresponding user. This is my database layer code:

```
public int loginUser(string userName, string pass)
    {
        int result = 0;
        var credentials = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("SearchForKnowledge", userName, pass);
        var settings = new MongoClientSettings
        {
            Credentials = new[] { credentials }
        };
        try
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
            var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userName", userName);
            var query = coll.Find(filter);
            //??????????
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

as you can see if the login is success im trying to return 1 and if it fails, 0 (for redirecting purposes). I am struggling to check if the username matches password set to it. At the moment I just made a filter, passed it to the method Find and im dead stuck at this point. How do I return that user's password from mongodb and compare it to the one passed as a parameter?

Comment: Do you really need to perform this check in your application? Perhaps when you establish the connection, the database itself will verify whether the password is correct?

Comment: My user information is stored in the SFK databse, which has Users collection where all the info is. not sure how to specify this path. Just for curiosity, is this what you had in mind: var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://" + userName + ":" + pass +"@localhost");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int loginUser(string userName, string pass)
    {
        int result = 0;
        //Here you use credentials for the connection, not the one passed
        //to the method:
        var credentials = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("SearchForKnowledge", connectionUsername, connectionPass);
        var settings = new MongoClientSettings
        {
            Credentials = new[] { credentials }
        };
        try
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
            var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
            var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userName", userName);
            var result = await coll.Find(filter).ToListAsync().First();
            if(result["Password"] == pass)
            {
               result = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: Hm, it keeps loading for a while and it returns me back to the login page. It seems like it cannot find correct username and password in the db. Im sure i input valid information

Comment: Seem's like you are confusing username and pass for the authentication on mongodb with username and pass of the user to login. 
These are 2 distinct things.
Your function loginUser are using the parameters passed to it to connect to the DB, but you are passing these same parameters to the query

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. But what should I put in credentials ("searchForKnowlege", "?", "?")
if those parameters are supposed to be my own "admin" login for the mongodb, i dont have it. All im trying to do is when user clicks "login" page, he could be able to login, so I dont really have any authentication on my db itself.